# Inverse mapping with custom mapper with mapstruct

Tags: java, mapstruct

I have a mapping defined as

```
@Mapping(source = "diagnoses", target = "diagnosisCode", qualifiedByName = "mapDiagnosisCodeAsList")
```

Where `mapDiagnosisCodeAsList` is defined as follows:

```
@Named("mapDiagnosisCodeAsList")
default List<String> retrieveDiagnosisCodeAsList(List<Diagnosis> aList) {
    if (CollectionUtils.isEmpty(aList)) {
        return new ArrayList<>();
    }
    return aList.stream().map(Diagnosis::getDiagnosisCode).collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Inverse mappings are handled using `@InheritInverseConfiguration`. How do I specify a custom mapping for the inverse mapping?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order for the inverse mapping to work you'll need to provide the inverse method as well.

```java
@Named("mapDiagnosisCodeAsList")
default List<Diagnosis> retrieveDiagnosisCodeAsList(List<String> aList) {
    if (CollectionUtils.isEmpty(aList)) {
        return new ArrayList<>();
    }
    return aList.stream().map(Diagnosis::new).collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

One other side note. I think that you don't really need the complexity of qualifiers to make this work. If you have only one `Diagnosis` to `String` and reverse you can do it without qualifiers (even without the list).

Your `@Mapping` will stay the same without `qualifiedByName` and you need to provided mapping from `Diagnosis` to `String` and reverse.

```java
default String diagnosisToString(Diagnosis diagnosis) {
    return diagnosis == null ? null : diagnosis.getDiagnosisCode();
}

default Diagnosis stringToDiagnosis(String diagnosisCode) {
    return diagnosis == null ? null : new Diagnosis(diagnosisCode);
}
```

The creation of the collection would be taken care by MapStruct.
Also I assume that `Diagnosis` has a constructor that takes the code.